# My laravel 5.4 not identify the new route i added

Tags: laravel

I have uploaded a site to cpanel and after some days i added a new route and now the site cannot identity the new route..and when i check php artisan route:list, i cant find it on the list

below are the new route i just added...both of them says page cannot be found..i have try to clear cache still i get same error

```
Route::get('foo', function () {
  return 'Hello World';
});


Route::get('/buycabletv', 'WalletController@buycabletv')->name('name.buycbl');
```

Comment: Did you also tried `php artisan route:clear`?

Answer (score 0):

php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:cache

this fixed it for me..